# django argument of type 'LazySettings' is not iterable; how then to check if a setting exists?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

```
from django.conf import settings

def my_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'LOCAL' in settings and settings.LOCAL:
        # do something
```

> TypeError at ... argument of type
>   'LazySettings' is not iterable

How then to check if a setting exists?  Otherwise I get an attribute error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the [`hasattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#hasattr) function:

```
if hasattr(settings, 'name_of_setting'):
    # the setting exists
else:
    # the setting does not exist
```

Comment: Um i got excited about your answer. but it still fails.           >>> if getattr(settings, 'JUNK'):
...   print 'hello'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/ben/Envs/menus_proto/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 277, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'JUNK'

Comment: You need to provide a default as the third argument, ie `getattr(settings, 'name', None)`. Or, since you don't need the actual value, use `hasattr(settings, 'name')` which just checks the name exists rather than getting its value.